# Filter api by multiple optional parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to filter repository method using multiple optional parameters. But I am not getting expected result.
Here is my query.

Here visitor entity contains multiple visits and one visits can have one contact person and one timeslot.

Thanks for the help

```
@Query("select v from Visitor v join v.visits visits join visits.contactPerson cp where "
            + "v.firstName=:firstName or :firstName is NULL or :firstName = '' and "
            + "visits.approvalStatus=:approvalStatus or :approvalStatus is NULL or :approvalStatus = '' "
            + "and cp.firstName=:firstName or :firstName is NULL or :firstName = '' ")
    public List<Visitor> findByFilter(@Param("firstName") String firstName,
            @Param("approvalStatus") String approvalStatus, @Param("firstName") String fName);
```

Comment: Can you share the `Visitor` entity? And please state what is the expected result.

Comment: added VIsitor entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to make the database understand your query the way you intend:

```
 + "(v.firstName=:firstName or :firstName is NULL or :firstName = '') and "
 + "(visits.approvalStatus=:approvalStatus or :approvalStatus is NULL or :approvalStatus = '') "
 + "and (cp.firstName=:firstName or :firstName is NULL or :firstName = '')"
```

The OR operator has a lower precedence than AND so `a OR b AND c OR d` is parsed as `a OR (b AND c) OR d`, not as `(a OR b) AND (c OR d)`.